# Entity Framework CTP 4. "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" - Even though there is no NULL value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ctp4

Im using EF CTP 4. I have a simple console app (for testing purposes) that is using EF to insert some data into a SQL database.

I have come to a problem where by upon inserting the item

```
using(var context = GetContext())
{
   BOB b = new BOB();
   b.Id = 1;

   context.Bobs.Add(b);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It throws the error: *{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'TestDB.dbo.BOB'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}*

The Table just has 1 field of *Id int NOT NULL* which is the primary key and is **not** an auto incremented Id.

On the creation of the DataContext I have this configuration, which yes does get fired.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<BOB>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
    builder.Entity<BOB>().MapSingleType().ToTable("BOB");
}
```

I have also pre-populated this table and then through the debugger been able to via *watch* load up this BOB object... so I am really stumped, as for being able to load up my BOB shows that all is right... however upon inserting a new one it crashes...

Comment: You might want to give it a try in [EF CTP 5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx)

Comment: also like to mention, that I am also connecting to another DataContext seperatly which communicates with a seperate database.

the idea being I would select the data from there and convert it to my bob object and insert it into the the other DB.

does using 2 different DataContexts in the same solution cause issues???

Comment: Updated to CTP5, however as I expected did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly specifying the `StoreGeneratedPattern`?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BOB>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id)
        .Property(p => p.Id)
            .StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.None;

builder.Entity<BOB>().MapSingleType().ToTable("BOB");
```

Comment: Had the same issue with CTP 5 here's the syntax:
modelBuilder.Entity<BOB>()
                .HasKey(p => p.Id)
                    .Property(p => p.Id)                                                       .HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.None);
 modelBuilder.Entity<BOB>().ToTable("BOB");

Answer (score 80):

i have the same issue here and it's really an ugly solution.

```
 [Key]
public Int64 PolicyID { get; set; }
```

this is NOT an auto generated number

then i hit the same error.

EF Code First CTP5

after apply this:

```
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
 public Int64 PolicyID { get; set; }
```

then it will work.

Comment: I disagree this is an ugly solution. This IMO is alot nicer than above. The annotations really help make things readable!

Comment: You can also do it in the map: `this.Property(t => t.id).HasColumnName("id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);`

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me.  IMO this isn't an ugly solution.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith - I agree...nice solution and most of all...It worked for me too! :) Thanks Sitem00n

Comment: great solution for having a entity framework key on a column that is not a identity column.

Comment: Use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` on the ID property of your model, if the identifier (ID) is generated on the server side rather then on the database side.

Comment: This solved same issue for me in EF6

Answer (score 33):

I'm using `EF 4.1, Model First` and came across this problem.  Here's how I solved it:

When using the Model Designer surface, when you create an Entity, you have to define a `Key` property, it defaults to `Id, int32`.

In my situation, I've chosen to use `Guids` for the `Id`, so I'd switch the `int32` to `Guid`.  But if you examine this Id after you create the entity, I saw that the Id's `'StoreGeneratedPattern'` had `'identity'` selected.  At first I didn't think that was a problem, but when I examined the SQL being used to insert into the database, it was a bit weird in that it wasn't sending my Id.  **Frustrating!**

But once I went back and changed the `'StoreGeneratedPattern'` from `'identity'` to `'none'`, regenerated the db and rebuilt the project, this strange message stopped happening:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'TestDB.dbo.BOB'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

FYI - upon viewing the sql some more it seems that if you have `identity` chosen for `StoreGeneratedPattern`, the EF saves the object to the db (sans Id), then immediately fetches back the identity and saves that back to your object.  i.e. this choice for `StoreGeneratedPattern` relies on the db to generate your Id, **NOT** your code!

Comment: Yup!  Thanks for this.  I was using a non-Int32 as a key and EF was overwriting what I had just written in there.  I'll pay closer attention to StoreGeneratedPattern from now on!

Answer (score 7):

You could also use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BOB>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id)
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

builder.Entity<BOB>().MapSingleType().ToTable("BOB");
```

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me when I had a primary key missing on the respected column (the identity column) in the db's schema.
I exported data between SQL servers, using SSMS Export tool and creating a new database, but didn't realize that it's exporting only the data, without keys.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation but in my case even setting `Identity` to `off` didn't help.

The problem was connected with Primary Key, which I've missed to add in my Entity Model.

Here is the script which was generating the model:

```
 CREATE TABLE [im].[SomeGroup]
 (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), -- this is mandatory for EF
    [OtherGroupId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
 )
```

The C# code for above is:

```
Insert(new SomeGroup
{
  // I'm not providing Id here, cause it will be auto-generated
  SomeGroupId = otherGroup.Id,
  Title = otherGroup.Title
});
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381324/806202) is also some explanation of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database first approach then first delete the respective entity from the edmx diagram and then Update the model from database , this will surely resolve your issue

Comment: The question clearly states they weren't using database-first. And this is quite a bold statement you make here, probably based on one case where this helped but disregarding many case where this surely won't help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case EntityFramework generated this code inside `Context.cs` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MODEL_OF_TABLE>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever(); // <= this line must remove
    ...
}
```

after remove this line, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue as well. For me my Dev DB Table for some reason didn't bring over the Key so EF didn't define my ID as a key.

**Note to anyone with this issue:** Make sure that your table that you trying to insert a new record into with an ID field is actually defined in your Context class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerEmail>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                .HasName("PK_tblCustomerEmail");

            entity.Property(e => e.Customer).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsUnicode(false);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I know that this question is somehow dated and an accepted solution has been already found, however I thought it would be useful if I share my findings.

I had this error today because I was using two different instances of the same `DataContext`. I was creating a new model with some properties - values for these properties were loaded from the database using one instance of the `DataContext`, then I was trying to push this newly created model into database calling first `Add()` and then `SaveChanges()` on a different instance of the `DataContext`. After I started using the same instance for both getting the values for the properties and actually adding and saving the new object - everything started working.