# Code first - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

This is my code, very simple...

```
 var newUser = new User();
        newUser.Id=id;
        newUser.Email = email;
       this.DataContext.Set<User>().Add(newUser);
        this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

The error I get is a sqlexception at `this.DataContext.SaveChanges();` stating that:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table
>   'xxxxx.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I have debugged and found that there is value in Id & Email in newUser at 
`this.DataContext.Set<User>().Add(newUser);`

If this is the case, how is the value becoming null?

The error stack trace:

```
[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +204
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +23
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
```

I have not been able to understand or solve this....

Would sincerely appreciate any help in this...

Regards
Arnab

**Solution**

Ok, thanks to Ladislav to point me in the right direction: 
Adding the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` solved the problem.

Comment: What is the type of id? Could be it that something is going wrong with generating the key in the database?

Comment: type is bigint in sqlserver, in User class it is long..
Also when I use normal entity framework without codefirst, it works

Comment: How did you map the user? EF code first by default expects that Id value is generated in the database (by Identity settings).

Comment: My User Class has two fields of which Id has [key] attribute. In db I have made Id primary key but have stated IsIdentity =no , so the value is not going to be generated in the db.
@Ladislav : what u r saying may be the problem, how do I solve this? I can not make isIdentity=yes

Comment: ok, thanks to Ladislav to point me in the right direction:

Adding the attribute [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] solved the  problem.

Answer (score 24):

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444407/entity-framework-ctp-4-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-even-though) it seems that entity framework expects by default that you insert into identity column.

To solve this try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BOB>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id)
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.None;

builder.Entity<BOB>().MapSingleType().ToTable("BOB");
```

or decorate your key in the POCO with:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //Fixed typo
public Int64 PolicyID { get; set; }
```

Comment: I believe the enum flag for that attribute is "DatabaseGeneratedOption" and not "DatabaseGenerationOption"

Comment: It worked for me too can any one explain why it happened how this attribute solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem, found your question, and then noticed this [Entity Framework 4.1 code-first KeyAttribute as non-identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820354/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-keyattribute-as-non-identity-column) question ( which has an attribute that solved my problem ).

If you define User as:

```
public class User
{
    [DataMember, Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The key here is putting the attributes:

- Key
- DatabaseGenerated

onto the ID column.  Apparently the issue we are fighting is that Entity Framework by default expects to do inserts with keys being identities.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by setting `StoreGeneratedPattern` on the column properties to `Computed`.

Step by step below:

1. Open your EDMX (double click in Visual Studio)
2. Right click on the column that causes the problem, select properties.
3. Change `StoreGeneratedPattern` to be `Computed`.

[image: From the IDE]
[image]

Hope that helps somebody.