# Why is EF trying to insert NULL in id-column?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am writing my project using Entity Framework 4.0 (Model first). At the beginning of the project, I faced with this problem: I am trying to insert the filled object in the database, but I get an exeption:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CategoryId', table 'ForumDB.dbo.Categories'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Code:

```
    Category usingCategory = new Category("Using Forums", "usingforums", 0);
    using (Context)
    {
        Context.Categories.AddObject(usingCategory);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I checked this object, and I am sure that it is filled.

Just in case:

```
public Category(string name, string urlName, int index)
{
    CategoryId = Guid.NewGuid();
    Name = name;
    UrlName = urlName;
    CategoryIndex = index;
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: what datatype is your CategoryId?

Comment: @Kyle, guid (uniqueidentifier).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework CTP 4. "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" - Even though there is no NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444407/entity-framework-ctp-4-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-even-though)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5338384/171703 - entity framework might be assuming that your CategoryId field is an identity and therefore passing null to the database expecting it to fill it for you.

Comment: It's good, but I use model-first, but in this question the problem has been solved in the scope of code-first.

Comment: @KovpaevAlexey The accepted answer in that question is for code first, but the specific linked answer in that question is for model first.

Comment: @hvd, this problem has solved when I added generating id on DB-side.

Comment: yep - EF assumes it's going to be genereated/incremented at the DB level, so it passed your `Id` col as `NULL`, even when there's a value in it. FYI, I think this answer is more specifically helpful for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5101369/1985648

Comment: TL;DR - add this to your key if it isn't auto-generated: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Answer (score 44):

I ran into this today and had to regenerate my EF classes from the database.

After doing that, I found that EF added:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

to this"Id" field that used to be an Identity column in the SQL but was changed to be app-assigned.

I think if you don't have that attribute EF won't actually send the ID to the database ('convention over configuration')

Comment: Worked for me too: didn't need to regenerate the classes, just added the attribute to the property and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I had created the table with int Id as PK, but had forgotten to set "Identity Specification" = True

Comment: You made my day !

Answer (score 7):

Try to add this into your model class .cs file:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

Or change your column CategoryId to identity:

```
    CategoryId int IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had a different schema other than default one. The name of the Id key was some how missing the that schema part - fixed that in the database and it all went well.
How it was ;

```
PK_TableName
```

How I changed it to

```
PK_mySchema.TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Met the same problem today.

Here is how I figured out the issue.

I had added the identity seed to the column initially but after that I removed it.
So I did not realize that when modifying the column definition in the Code first, the Id

```
Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("Id")
    .HasColumnType("int")
    .IsRequired();
```

So Entity framework figured out that it was an Identity column and I got the exception above.

To fix this, I added the following:

```
HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
```

so the final piece was something like:

```
Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("Id")
    .HasColumnType("int")
    .IsRequired()
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

İf Model first try block

```
[Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
 public Int64 PolicyID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but here's how I managed to fix it.

1. I included these attributes to my int PK in my models. (to give way for my seed in configuration.cs)
   `[Key]` 
   `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`
2. After I've inserted my seed I use the SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio and went to the table of this model by right clicking the table and press 'View Designer'
   [image]
3. Below you will see the script generated for creating that table. Insert this command right after your primary key property.

   `IDENTITY(1,1)`

[image]

4. Apply script changes by clicking 'Update' just above the table view (left corner) 
   [image]
5. After updating the database, go back to your model and change this attribute:

   `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
6. Save, Add migration then Update Database should do it.

Everytime you insert, it will now increment depending on what you specified on the IDENTITY script.