# Cannot insert NULL into column while value is not null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

So im having this weird problem with trying to add an instance to the entities. Its a asp.net application using EF 6.0.

The exception:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderId',
>   table 'BETA.MDF.dbo.Orders'; column
>   does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

My code:

```
User user = (User)Session["CurrentUser"];
BetaEntities entities = new BetaEntities();

Beta.Order order = new Beta.Order();
order.OrderId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
order.OrderedBy = user.UserId;
order.HandledBy = entities.Users.Where(x => x.Rank > 0).Select(i => i.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

entities.Orders.Add(order);

entities.SaveChanges();
```

My table:
[image]

Also this is my order class, i already tried `[Databasegenerated]`

```
public partial class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderedBy { get; set; }
    public int HandledBy { get; set; }
}
```

Example entry:

[image]
Please tell me if you need more details.

EDIT:

I tried setting the database datatype of OrderID to UNIQUEIDENTIEFIER and updated the entity model so the database should generate the guid(and i removed  itself but i still get the same exception.

This is my new class:

```
public partial class Order
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public System.Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderedBy { get; set; }
    public int HandledBy { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

If i make OrderID NULLABALE and remove the primary key i get the following exception:

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

But this can be resolved by adding a primary key :( so removing the PK and making it NULLABLE isnt working.

Also i need to assign to GUID myself for further purposes so letting the database assign the guid itself(with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`) is also not an option.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855100/why-is-ef-trying-to-insert-null-in-id-column) not sure but it might help you and good luck

Comment: You get pretty clear exception message: _Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderId', because column does not allow nulls_. Just set column to allow `NULL` values.

Comment: identity for string is useless

Comment: If i set to column to allow nulls then it cant be a primary key and i want to be a primary key.

Comment: Then why you setting `NULL` to the identity column, what is purpose?

Comment: @Fabio Im not sure i understand you, my problem is that it says OrderId has a value of NULL but it doesnt. I have never set orderId to NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you set `DatabaseGenerated` attribute to the `OrderId` column.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public string OrderId { get; set; }
```

With this attribute EF will ignore value you set to `OrderId` and "try" generate unique value, but generating unique value will not work for `string` and `OrderId` will be `NULL` when `INSERT` query is generated.

If you are using EF "code first" then change type of `OrderId` to `Guid` and remove next line from code

```
order.OrderId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

And leave `DatabaseGenerated` attribute as it is.
When using `DatabaseGenerated` attribute for column - means that value of this column will be generated by database.

After changing your structure of `Order` class, you need update database accordingly. If you using "code-first" approach then you need generate migration script and run it against your database. In "database-first" approach you need update database manually

Even you said removing `DatabaseGenerated` attribute doesn't help, it will be most simpler solution as suggested by Ivan Stoev in the comments.
Because you generating unique string by yourself using `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

Comment: If I remove it I still get the same exception

Comment: There's two things missing from this answer: change the type of `OrderId` to `Guid`, yes. But also adjust the column type in the database to match, and give it a default constraint of `newid()` (or `newsequentialid()`).

Comment: In case when you remove it - it should work if database was updated accordingly.

Comment: @hvd, not sure but isn't migration script will do it automatically?

Comment: @Fabio If migrations are enabled, maybe, I don't know. But the OP didn't specify migrations, so I'm not assuming they're enabled.

Comment: I tried this answer but i still get the same exception :(

Comment: Since OP is specifying the `OrderId` value for new entities, I'm wondering why don't you recommend removing the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute, which is more natural for what they are doing rather than changing their table filed type, removing code etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev :) - I did in the comment of this answer, but OP said it doesn't work

Comment: I also added the result of removing the PK and making it nullable. Also i need to assign the OrderID myself for further purposes in the code so DATABASEGENERATED("identity") wont be an option im afraid.