# [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I probably have spent 4 hours now and tried
Code First approach  and
Database first approach

```
 db.MoveJobs.Add(moveJob);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

When a row is inserted it gives me

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'aspnet-AccountVerification.Web3.dbo.MoveJobs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
public class MoveJob
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I need to generate incrementally a key for every itself for a new row. No Stack overflow / Forums / or something has helped.

I strangely worked yesterday though. I cant get where i went wrong

Comment: That just means your `Id` column is not identity column in _database_.

Comment: it seems you are sending null for colum Id..can you check the data you are sending

Comment: I have made changes to Id column is as identity column.                     [id]    INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY,                                                                
  Im using local mdf file via server explorer. How can i make changes permanent / save ?

Comment: you don't need use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`. the property `id` by default is key and identity. first, remove this attribute and drop your database, after do this add a new migration. do you use fluent API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is EF trying to insert NULL in id-column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855100/why-is-ef-trying-to-insert-null-in-id-column)

Comment: which approach does this error come from? Your attempt seems to be a mix between code first and database first - you are trying code first, but your database does not match your model - as @Evk explained, is your property configured as identity, so EF won't pass the parameter as it suspects it to be computed by DBMS, while the database expects the value (the column is not Identity or at least not with a valid seed/inc)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`.

The property `id` by default is key and identity. First remove this attribute and drop your database, after do this add a new migration.