# "Cannot insert the value NULL into column " but my column is Nullable... Entity Framework 5 asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I started a project with asp.net MVC internet aplication...
I made some changes to the default code...
I created my own user context:

```
public class UsersDBContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

And I made some changes to the AccountModel:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int? test { get; set; }

}
```

I added this column test. As you can see , this column is nullable.....
But in runtime I get this error when I try to register an user:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'test'.column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The error happens in this line:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Does anyone know any solution?

EDIT: Migration Code:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "test", c => c.Int());
    }

public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "test", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what data type you use in your entity.. if the database column itself is not nullable it will fail.

Comment: I already updated the dataBase...

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444407/entity-framework-ctp-4-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-even-though?rq=1

Comment: @ZeCariocaSilva, it doesn't sound like you update to the db took.  Can you show us your db in SSMS (or the result of a describe) to confirm that it is in fact updated to allow nulls on that column?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your entity framework edmx after you made the change to the DB? I have found sometimes that using the update function in the edmx designer after making a change doesn't work very well.  I would delete the table from the edmx designer and then re-add it and then rebuild your solution.