# How get Entity Framework 6.0.0.0 to use SQL Identity and Seed for ID field

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I'm very new to Entity Framework, so I'm sure this is a schoolboy error. I've check a few links here on Stackoverflow such as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444407/entity-framework-ctp-4-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-even-though/5101369#5101369), which gave me some things to try, but this has not fixed the issue.

I have a SQL database with a "tblPerson". The Primary Key is "PersonID" and it is set as the Identity, with a Seed=1 (int).

I then have a C#\ASP.NET front-end that I'm building.

I have a Class for Person:

```
    public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,10}$")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Data Access Layer class that then handles the writing to the database:

```
    public class PersonDAL : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("tblPerson");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(x => x.PersonID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I am telling it that PersonID field should be a database-generated identity.

Here is my code inside the Controller that calls an "Add":

```
        public ActionResult Add(Person obj) //Validation runs here
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            PersonDAL personDAL = new PersonDAL();
            personDAL.People.Add(obj);
            personDAL.SaveChanges();
            personDAL.Dispose();
            obj = null;
            return View("AddPerson", obj);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("AddPerson", obj);
        }
    }
```

"obj" is populated via the razor view, but it will have PersonID=null, however, when I instantiate the Data Access Layer, and try to Add and Save, I would expect this to work, however, I get the error:

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PersonID'  the column does not allow nulls."

Any tips would be gratefully appreciated.

UPDATE: It seems that in my PersonDAL Data Access Layer, this line never gets triggered: `public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }`So, I am not sure why the line on the Controller `personDAL.People.Add(obj);` is failing to set it? (I can prove all this by pulling back People as a a List to the controller, and it's count is 0). Any ideas anyone?

UPDATE - SILLY ERROR!! - I somehow managed to uncheck "Identity" in the SQL table design for PersonID in tblPerson. NOW FIXED.

Comment: One issue I can see is you need to move this line: base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); to the end of OnModelCreating.

Comment: Also you can use attribute instead of overriding OnModelCreating https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh425941(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StephenBrickner - Thanks for the tip, I have now done that, but it didn't fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @chameleon86.Thanks. I had tried tried that originally, but to be sure, I commented out the line in the override code in the DataAccessLayer Class, and then added this line above "PersonID" in the Person class, but I still get the same error: [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Answer (score 0):

SILLY ERROR!! - I somehow managed to uncheck "Identity" in the SQL table design for PersonID in tblPerson. NOW FIXED.